# Subclassing UIView and displaying multiple instances

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiview

I am trying to do the following:

1. Display an instance of a custom `UIView`. This `UIView` subclass should load it's content from Interface Builder, because it shows stuff that I don't want to create by hand. *My question is*: How can I load from Interface Builder in a `UIView` subclass?
2. I will eventually animate this view out of the screen and release it. (I know how to do that :-) )
3. GOTO Step 1, i.e creating a new instance of my `UIView` and display it.

Probably a noobish question, but I can't seem to figure it out. I would appreciate some help, Fabian

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To load an interface from Interface Builder you need to use a UIViewController. If you don't use interface builder though, you can create a uiview subclass, create your interface, and then create instances of your class. For every class all you need to do is this:

```
MyView *view = [[MYView alloc] initWithFrame:theFrame];
MyView *secondView = [[MyView alloc] initWithFrame:theFrame];
//do stuff with the views
//release the views
[view release];
[secondView release];
```

Answer (score 3):

In iOS 4.0+, create an instance of `UINib` referencing your nib file (`+nibWithNibName:bundle:`), then instantiate the objects in the nib with `-[UINib instantiateWithOwner:options:]`.

If you need to target iOS 3.x, too, call:

```
[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:owner:options:]
```

which returns an array of the objects in the nib file.

Comment: I have used this approach, but I have not succeeded in making the corners of the rounded edged view transparent. My NIB loaded custom UIView is a cornered rectangle, not a rounded rectangle. Any suggestions?

Comment: What does one have to do with the other?